# Does this collection operator method also work on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, core-data

```
NSNumber *salaryOverhead = [anEmployee valueForKeyPath:@"department.employees.@sum.salary"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a key path so it should work. What's the ampersand for?

### Edit:

That was a strange brain blank. The ampersand is of course the @sum [collections operator of the key-value programming protocol.](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/ArrayOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE)

Comment: Do you mean the @sum in the key path? I didn't get that by 100% yet, but I believe it's a reference to a special function which is invoked on an salary array to gather the total amount of salary. Probably an array with 12 salaries per year so you can calculate how much the total salary is. Not sure...would be happy if someone can give better explanation.

Comment: See my edit. With the exception of binding, there is very little in Core Data on the make that you can't use on iOS. I think there are some value transformers that are not available. 99% of the stuff you read in the Core Data docs will work on iOS.